# get Json Object encased in another Json

Tags: java, android, json

i'm stuck with a JSon problem, i'm trying to get a value contained in a JSon Object witch is itself Contained in another JSon Object.  The returned JSon is like this " {"id":25,"name":"aaaaaaaa:eeeeegh","dishes_number":2,"description":"tttttttttttttf","country":{"code":"FR","name":"France"},"type":{"id":2,"name":"Main course"}} " 
and i want to get the value od code in Country and the id in Type

[image]

here's my code

```
  try{
        JSONArray json = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
        Courses coun;
        for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
            JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
            coun = new Courses();

            //          Log.i(TAG, "Nom Pays :  " + jsonObject.get("name"))
            coun.setName((String) jsonObject.get("name"));
            coun.setId((int) jsonObject.get("id"));
            coun.setCountryCode((String) jsonObject.get("code"));
            coun.setDescription((String) jsonObject.get("description"));
        /*    coun.setCourseTypeId((int) jsonObject.get("code"));
            coun.setDishesNumber((int) jsonObject.get("code")); */


            repas.add(coun);
        }
    }catch (JSONException je){
        je.printStackTrace();
    };
```

it give me the answer " org.json.JSONException: No value for code " when i run the app

Thanks you for your help

Comment: get the country, then the code from the country.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  try{
    JSONArray json = new JSONArray(sb.toString());
    Courses coun;
    for(int i=0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);
        coun = new Courses();

        //          Log.i(TAG, "Nom Pays :  " + jsonObject.get("name"))
        coun.setName((String) jsonObject.get("name"));
        coun.setId((int) jsonObject.get("id"));
      //get des country
         JSONObject country = jsonObject.getJSONObject("country");
       //get code and other informations of country




      coun.setCountryCode(country.getString("code"));
        coun.setDescription((String) jsonObject.get("description"));
    /*    coun.setCourseTypeId((int) jsonObject.get("code"));
        coun.setDishesNumber((int) jsonObject.get("code")); */


        repas.add(coun);
    }
}catch (JSONException je){
    je.printStackTrace();
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Code field is nested in the country, so you need to get country first:

```
((JSONObject)jsonObject.get("country")).get("code")
```

The same way you can get type and nested id field from it.

P.S. Me test code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String jsonStr = "[{\"id\":25,\"name\":\"aaaaaaaa:eeeeegh\",\"dishes_number\":2,\"description\":\"tttttttttttttf\",\"country\":{\"code\":\"FR\",\"name\":\"France\"},\"type\":{\"id\":2,\"name\":\"Main course\"}}]";

    try {
      JSONArray json = new JSONArray(jsonStr);

      for (int i = 0; i < json.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject jsonObject = json.getJSONObject(i);

        System.out.println(((JSONObject)jsonObject.get("country")).get("code"));
      }
    } catch (JSONException je) {
      je.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
```

Output:

```
FR
```

Comment: hello, it give me this eror : Error:(173, 71) error: void cannot be dereferenced

Comment: you are doing something wrong then, let me provide my test code - I will add it to the answer.

Comment: Update your question with the latest code you have, so this way we can help you.

Comment: thank you for your help @Sergei i'll retry it but the answer given by kfir88 already works